# Case insensitive sort in Nemo

Tags: nemo, sort, case-insensitive

So I'm trying to get so special characters are on top followed by numbers, then letters case insensitive.

I've added `export LC_ALL=C` to my `.profile`, but the result is case sensitive.

Is there a better way to do this where it will sort special characters on top followed by numbers, then letters case insensitive?